# Execution default-cli of goal org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:5.2.1:run failed:

Tags: java, spring-boot, openrewrite

I encountered an error when trying to execute `rewrite-maven-plugin` version 5.2.1 on my  project:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:5.2.1:run (default-cli) on project sms-server: Execution default-cli of goal org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:5.2.1:run failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:5.2.1:run: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/Caffeine has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:5.2.1
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/home/daniel/.m2/repository/org/openrewrite/maven/rewrite-maven-plugin/5.2.1/rewrite-maven-plugin-5.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/home/daniel/.m2/repository/org/openrewrite/recipe/rewrite-spring/5.0.1/rewrite-spring-5.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/home/daniel/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/annotations/24.0.1/annotations-24.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/home/daniel/.m2/repository/org/openrewrite/rewrite-gradle/8.1.2/rewrite-gradle-8.1.2.jar
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your error message *"has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognises class file versions up to 52.0".* This looks like a Java Version Issue. Recheck your Java Version by running  `java -version` on your terminal and ensure it is compatible with the minimum version requirements for the openrewrite dependency you are using . If you are running a lower version, you could consider either upgrading your java version (if thats possible) or using older versions of this dependency.
Check out this guide
https://docs.openrewrite.org/running-recipes/getting-started

Comment: when I am using rewrite-maven-plugin v-5.0.0 and rewrite-spring v-5.0.0 for spring boot migration from 1.5 to 2.7. I am getting following error when running mvn rewrite:run.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:5.0.0:run (default-cli) on project project-name: Execution default-cli of goal org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:5.0.0:run failed: Unable to construct Java8Parser.: InvocationTargetException: ANNOTATION_PROCESSOR_MODULE_PATH -> [Help 1] [ERROR]

Comment: Your version of caffeine requires Java 11; best to then run on at least Java 11.